# binary '=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type '_Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, set

Hello everyone I was writing below program But eventually I get to know
That I did a syntax mistake somewhere nor the code was compiling neither it was pointing any line no where the error has occurred Please help

Error :

> `Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2678   binary '=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type '_Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  Project5    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\utility 68`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
using namespace std;
vector<int> a;
set<pair<int, int>> sat;
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    a.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int u;
        cin >> u;
        sat.insert({ u,i });
    }
    reverse(sat.begin(), sat.end());
    ///int pos = 0;
    ///set<pair<int, int>>::iterator it ;
    auto it = sat.begin();
    int prev = it->first;
    a[it->second] = 1;
    it++;
    for (; it != sat.end(); it++) {
        if (it->first == prev) {
            a[it->second] = a[(next(it, -1))->second];
        }
        else {
            a[it->second] = a[(next(it, -1))->second] + 1;
            prev = it->first;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: What do you think `reverse` would do on a set? That's the error I see. If you want the set to sort in reverse that's done a different way. Alternatively you could just iterate in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is the first line of the error message, it should be followed by additional messages that progressively report each level of template instantiation and where it came from, eventually winding up in your code. If you were to carefully examine each line of the error message, eventually you will wind up at the following line in your code:

```
reverse(sat.begin(), sat.end());
```

`sat` is a `std::set`. `std::reverse` reverses in place the contents of the container. Unfortuntely, you cannot reverse in place the contents of `std::set`. `std::set` does not work this way. `std::set` is an ***ordered container*** It always arranges the values in the `std::set` in a predetermined order.

It is not very clear what the intent of your program is, but, anyway, this is the reason for your error message. You will have to either switch to a different container, maybe a `std::vector` or a `std::list`.